# How to split a string and compare for equality in Java?

Tags: java

suppose we have
String str = "Hello-Hello1";
How do we split it and compare it to see if it is equal or not?

This is what I wrote, but it does not give me the result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "Hello-Hello1";
        
        String [] a = str.split("-");
        
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i]+ " ");
        }

        for(int first =0; first<a.length; first++) {
            for(int second =first+1; second<a.length; second ++) {
                if(a[first].equals(a[second])){
                    System.out.println(a[first]);
                }
            }
        }
         
    }
```

Comment: First, welcome to SO, can you give more information about what you want to split (like split by char "-" or split by space...", what you want to compare (compare the first part with the second part or we will have multiple part after split) ,......

Comment: @DangNguyen, Thank you, sure can you please check my answer. yes I want to split the string by "-" then it gives me array of string now I want to compare the result

Comment: @Sultana - Please give a concrete example for what you are trying to accomplish.
For example, for the input "Hello-Hello1" what do you want to the output to be. The more examples the better. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis, so I have a string that i need to split it by "-" once we split string the result is an array of string which in my case has two elements {Hello, Hello1} how could we compare these two to check whether they are equal or not. you can check the questio again I post my code in it.

Comment: Why not just use `if(a[0].equals(a[1])) {...}`, instead of those 2 `for` loops surrounding the comparison? I think you have made things far more complicated than needed. And also a check, first, to ensure the array has a length of 2.

Answer (score 0):

First, you split your string like shown here:
[How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java), then compare them using the equals method: `a[0].equals(a[1]);`

Comment: I tried it but does not work. check the question again i added my code

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping
Here is the answer

```
public class SplitStringAndCompare {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Hello-Hello1";
        
        String [] a = str.split("-");
        
        if(a[0].equals(a[1])) {
            System.out.println(a[0]+ " is equal to " + a[1]);
        } else {
            System.out.println(a[0]+ " is not equal to "+ a[1]);
        }
        
    }
```